# Why does my FPS character keep spinning forever in Unity3D?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I'm new to Unity and I'm using the [FPS Microgame](https://learn.unity.com/project/fps-template).  As soon as I play the Microgame, my character starts spinning forever. I can still shoot and move, but it will not stop rotating & spinning.  It's like I'm permanently dizzy and spinning.  I haven't changed anything except adding a new room.  I disabled my other monitor, so I don't know what the problem is.  My version is 2019.4.15f1.  I normally ask my parents for help but they do not know anything about Unity.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem may come from your "Input manager".
Try to open it and see what could possibly go wrong with the input used for the FPS controller rotation (I guess it should be mousX)

Comment: Thanks, This solved my problem.  I had to change the sensitivity of my player input.